# Taking an eclipse java project and packing it into a jar?

Tags: java, executable-jar

Right now i've written a simple SWT application using eclipse, and I want to pack it into an executable .jar file so I can give it out to friends and such. But I have the following problems:
-Right now i'm reading files by using their filename in the program, and putting them in the root folder of the eclipse project. That works fine for running in eclipse, but when I export to jar they're not in the jar. Is there a way to put them in the jar and access them in the code?
-I also need the SWT .jar dependencies or whatever its called(the files you need for SWT).

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream() API.

Comment: I tried that, but I still don't know how to add the resources(an image and a couple of text files) into the project in eclipse so that that line would actually work.

Comment: Just put them into your java source folder alongside your .java files. Use folder structure that you feel is appropriate. Let's say you source folder is [project]/src and you place your image in [project]/src/foo/bar/MyImage.png, you would use getResourceAsStream() API with "foo/bar/MyImage.png" path.

Comment: Forgot to mention is that getResourceAsStream() will work regardless of how you run your java app and whether or not the classes are in an exploded folder structure or in a JAR. That's why that API is the preferred way for Java applications to access their resources (images, text files, whatever).

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is include these files in the with the source code of your project, then to have access to then have a look at [this link](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=392)

Comment: You mean manually put them in the .jar? Then the code to access them in my eclipse project won't compile so i can't export the .jar.

Also, that website has some sort of CPALead thing wanting me to do a survey before I can read the stuff. I caught a glimpse of FileReader, and I already have it set up reading using a Scanner, so I don't think that should matter.

Comment: What i mean, in the src folder, where you find the source, among those those folder you should put a new folder with those files you want included. This will make the jar package to include them. And you ask about how to read them, if you already know how, why did you ask ?